The STM32G4 ADC and SPI slave conflict, this causes the ADC register to sometimes read a value of 0
The chip I use is STM32G473VC, which is configured with 7 channel ADC and SPI slave station
When the SPI DMA transmission is not started, the ADC works fine.
However, when the SPI DMA transfer is started, the ADC occasionally reads a value of 0.
The transmission cycle of the SPI master station is 8ms.
SPI needs to transmit important data, so SPI has a higher priority than ADC.
Whether I use the ADC DMA, interrupt, or direct poll conversion to read the register, it is possible for this 0 value to occur.
What might be the cause of this?

Please [edit] your question to show us the relevant code. It's unlikely that the STM32 ADC is failing due to an SPI transaction. It's more likely there's a bug in your code.

Thanks for the suggestion, but because as soon as I stop the SPI transfer, the ADC will work perfectly.

You might want to read the errata for your chip - there are some that could cause the ADC to return 0.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
